# How to temporary swap drivers in linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, drivers

I've made a new out-of-the-tree linux kernel module which is supposed to be loaded when a `usb` keyboard has been detected by my user space hotplug tool `udev`.

The problem is that although my module is loaded successfully (manually using `insmod`) and my driver is ready to respond to the events, the default `usbhid` driver has been already loaded, which, of course, is nice because it allows me to use the system as my driver is still in development. So when I `rmmod usbhid`, I assume that my system switches to my experimental driver (hard to tell because usb human interface is not detected).

Therefore, is it possible to temporary switch the drivers or (even better) test the experimental driver even if the `usbhid` is working?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround might be to perform those commands via SSH, or in a virtual machine with USB passtrough.

When I want to quickly try some modules, I write in a shell something like:

`rmmod usbhid; insmod my_module; sleep 15; rmmod my_module; modprobe usb_hid`

Another quick workaround for input issues in this situation is to use another input method than USB HID devices: PS/2, or virtual like the remote keyboard from kdeconnect or synergy.

The virtual machine is in my opinion the better setup if you are doing some serious kernel development, as it will avoid crashing yours if any problem arises.

Besides these workarounds, you might be interested in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26132/how-to-assign-usb-driver-to-device#29879) for a more permanent setup.